# Extracting only dates from a list

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have been trying to split a column of a data frame into 3 separate columns. I was able to successfully split to 2 of the desired columns, but am having trouble extracting the date (year only). 
This is the code I used to split the column into 2 of the columns I wanted:

```
wines$Winery <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(wines$wine), "[0-9]{4}"), "[", 1) 
wines$Name <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(wines$wine), "[0-9]{4}"), "[", 2)
```

I have tried using gsub to get rid of all non-digit characters, however there are numerical characters that I do not want to grab. All I am wanting is the 4 digit year from the center of the column, and not all rows have a year listed.

```
#           winery                                               wine
# 1  Charles Smith                Charles Smith 2012 Royal City Syrah
# 2     K Vintners                  K Vintners 2012 Cattle King Syrah
# 3     K Vintners                        K Vintners 2012 Klein Syrah
# 4   Two Vintners              Two Vintners 2013 Make Haste Cinsault
# 5     K Vintners                   K Vintners 2012 The Hidden Syrah
# 6         Kerloo                      Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Malbec
# 7    Betz Family     Betz Family 2012 Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon
# 8         Kerloo Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon
# 9         Efeste            Efeste 2012 Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon
# 10  Two Vintners        Two Vintners 2013 Boushey Vineyard Orenache
# 11    K Vintners                K Vintners 2012 Morrison Lane Syrah
# 12    K Vintners                    K Vintners 2012 The Creator Red
```

This data was collected through web scraping, so I have included an image of what the data looks like, but there are over 1000 rows

**Data**

```
wines <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "winery wine
'Charles Smith' 'Charles Smith 2012 Royal City Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Cattle King Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Klein Syrah'
'Two Vintners' 'Two Vintners 2013 Make Haste Cinsault'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 The Hidden Syrah'
Kerloo 'Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Malbec'
'Betz Family' 'Betz Family 2012 Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon'
Kerloo 'Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon'
Efeste 'Efeste 2012 Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon'
'Two Vintners' 'Two Vintners 2013 Boushey Vineyard Orenache'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Morrison Lane Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 The Creator Red'")
```

Comment: It is better to provide input in the format we can use to experiment code against. An image is not useful to that task.

Comment: do this: `dput(head(wines,15))` and add the output to your question.

Comment: looks like eventually you will want `read.csv(text = gsub(' (?=\\d{4})|(?<=\\d{4}) ', ',', wines$wine, perl = TRUE), header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

```
wines <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "winery wine
'Charles Smith' 'Charles Smith 2012 Royal City Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Cattle King Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Klein Syrah'
'Two Vintners' 'Two Vintners 2013 Make Haste Cinsault'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 The Hidden Syrah'
Kerloo 'Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Malbec'
'Betz Family' 'Betz Family 2012 Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon'
Kerloo 'Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon'
Efeste 'Efeste 2012 Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon'
'Two Vintners' 'Two Vintners 2013 Boushey Vineyard Orenache'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Morrison Lane Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 The Creator Red'")
```

To get just the dates you can sub out all non digit characters

```
gsub('\\D', '', wines$wine)
# [1] "2012" "2012" "2012" "2013" "2012" "2013" "2012" "2013" "2012" "2013" "2012" "2012"
```

Or by splitting your string

```
do.call('rbind', strsplit(wines$wine, ' (?=\\d{4})|(?<=\\d{4}) ', perl = TRUE))
#      [,1]            [,2]   [,3]                                    
#  [1,] "Charles Smith" "2012" "Royal City Syrah"                      
#  [2,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "Cattle King Syrah"                     
#  [3,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "Klein Syrah"                           
#  [4,] "Two Vintners"  "2013" "Make Haste Cinsault"                   
#  [5,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "The Hidden Syrah"                      
#  [6,] "Kerloo"        "2013" "Stone Tree Malbec"                     
#  [7,] "Betz Family"   "2012" "Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon"         
#  [8,] "Kerloo"        "2013" "Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon"
#  [9,] "Efeste"        "2012" "Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon"           
# [10,] "Two Vintners"  "2013" "Boushey Vineyard Orenache"             
# [11,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "Morrison Lane Syrah"                   
# [12,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "The Creator Red"
```

Or getting it all in one go (which is basically the same as the above)

```
read.csv(text = gsub(' (?=\\d{4})|(?<=\\d{4}) ', ',', wines$wine, perl = TRUE), header = FALSE)

#               V1   V2                                     V3
# 1  Charles Smith 2012                       Royal City Syrah
# 2     K Vintners 2012                      Cattle King Syrah
# 3     K Vintners 2012                            Klein Syrah
# 4   Two Vintners 2013                    Make Haste Cinsault
# 5     K Vintners 2012                       The Hidden Syrah
# 6         Kerloo 2013                      Stone Tree Malbec
# 7    Betz Family 2012          Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon
# 8         Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon
# 9         Efeste 2012            Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon
# 10  Two Vintners 2013              Boushey Vineyard Orenache
# 11    K Vintners 2012                    Morrison Lane Syrah
# 12    K Vintners 2012                        The Creator Red
```

Comment: The lines that do not have a date seem to contain NV, I altered what you re suggesting to include that    `x <- do.call('rbind', strsplit(wines$wine, ' (?=\\d{4})|(?<=\\d{4})|(?=(NV))|(?<=(NV)) ', perl = TRUE))` but it is splitting between the N and V. Is there a way to ensure that the entire NV ends up in the date column? For example in the line `14 Hands NV Brut Methode Champenoise Sparkling`

Comment: @JamieLeigh: That requirement should be part of the question.

Comment: @JamieLeigh just use `\\d{4}|NV` instead of `\\d`, does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a work around like this: replace all the substrings you need to split out with some custom delimiter string that you will not find in your data (say, `gsub("\\s*(\\d{4}|\\bNV\\b)\\s*","#-#\\1#-#", wines$wine)` to enclose 4 digit chunks and `NV` as whole words, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xK2wL0/1)), and then split with that pattern:

```
wines <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "winery wine
'Charles Smith' 'Charles Smith 2012 Royal City Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Cattle King Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Klein Syrah'
'Two Vintners' 'Two Vintners 2013 Make Haste Cinsault'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 The Hidden Syrah'
Kerloo 'Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Malbec'
'Betz Family' 'Betz Family 2012 Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon'
Kerloo 'Kerloo 2013 Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon'
Efeste 'Efeste 2012 Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon'
'Two Vintners' 'Two Vintners 2013 Boushey Vineyard Orenache'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 Morrison Lane Syrah'
'K Vintners' 'K Vintners 2012 The Creator Red'
'K Vintners2' '14 Hands NV Brut Methode Champenoise Sparkling'
")
wines$wine <- gsub("\\s*(\\d{4}|\\bNV\\b)\\s*","#-#\\1#-#", wines$wine, perl=T)
do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(wines$wine),'#-#',fixed=TRUE))
##  [,1]            [,2]   [,3]                                    
## [1,] "Charles Smith" "2012" "Royal City Syrah"                      
## [2,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "Cattle King Syrah"                     
## [3,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "Klein Syrah"                           
## [4,] "Two Vintners"  "2013" "Make Haste Cinsault"                   
## [5,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "The Hidden Syrah"                      
## [6,] "Kerloo"        "2013" "Stone Tree Malbec"                     
## [7,] "Betz Family"   "2012" "Le Parrain Cabernet Sauvignon"         
## [8,] "Kerloo"        "2013" "Stone Tree Vineyard Cabernet Sauvignon"
## [9,] "Efeste"        "2012" "Big Papa Cabernet Sauvignon"           
##[10,] "Two Vintners"  "2013" "Boushey Vineyard Orenache"             
##[11,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "Morrison Lane Syrah"                   
##[12,] "K Vintners"    "2012" "The Creator Red"                       
##[13,] "14 Hands"      "NV"   "Brut Methode Champenoise Sparkling"
```